# Suppress C4189 in Visual Studio for each

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, foreach

I'm working on Visual Studio 2013 and got a simple loop

```
for each (const std::string &foo in stringList)
{ 
    /*Things happen here where foo is never used for*/
}
```

In the loop I pop N elements from the list so I dont use foo here and got C4189 warning (w4) which I want to suppress here.

I looked around and found several solutions like

```
for each (const std::string &foo in stringList)
{ 
    (void)foo;
    /*Things happen here where foo is never used for*/
}
```

or define solutions like `#define UNUSED __pragma(warning(suppress:4189))`

Personally I like the define solution, which seems not to work in the loop because I still got the warning if I use the define.

So my question:

Is there a way to suppress the warning without setting compiler flags? I **don't** want to use an extra line inside the loop to suppress the warning.

Comment: Can you change your code to use a [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Comment: @NathanOliver you mean c++11 style for(auto x : ....)? Then I could, but I want to use the vs13 version. For me it's more readable

Comment: So don't use for range, moreover, mutating `stringList` in the block is dangerous in for range.

Comment: I think you only want `while (!stringList.empty()) { stringList.pop(); /**/}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 well while would be the easiest way to avoid that problem I agree and guess I'll swap my ranged loop. However I'm still interested if it's possible to avoid the warning. Maybe there's something like `for each(void in stringlist) {}` available.

Comment: @Nitro.de What is the sense to use this form of loop if foo is not used?

Comment: What is this syntax? It's not C++. If you want to use some implementation extensions in your code for subjective reasons then that's your choice, but I'd ask (and I don't think this is an isolated opinion; Nathan certainly agrees) that you stick to standard features in your questions here unless you have an objective reason not to. It makes it easier for us and takes doubt out of the equation. _(tl;dr what you do in private is your business but doesn't mean you can't use ranged-for here!)_

Comment: Anyway, these guys are right: this is the _wrong_ solution to your problem, and that it is the _wrong_ solution to your problem is why you are getting a warning. Suppressing the warning is going in the wrong direction. Alas, I cannot answer the question as posed so this'll have to be a comment. :)

Comment: The unreferenced string will be used in future however I took jarods advice and changed to while for now. @LightnessRacesinOrbit the for each isn't c++11 [it's a msvc specific](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202(v=vs.80).aspx) thing here

Comment: @Nitro.de: I know it's not C++11. That was my point.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17:

```
    for ([[maybe_unused]] const auto &foo in stringList)
{ 
    /*Things happen here where foo is never used for*/
}
```